# Using If Then Else statement with vbs message box

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, vbscript

I am attempting to use VBS to determine what answer a user clicks when a dialog box opens. I want to set it up so that when the user clicks "yes", the VBS executes a batch file using an If Then Else Statement. Here is the code I have so far. The message box opens but the .bat does not.

```
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
x=msgbox("Do you wish for windows Shutdown?" ,4+16, "Confirm")
If returnvalue=6 Then
    shell.run "||||File Adress||||test.bat"
End If
```

The vertical bars signify my comments.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the result of `msgbox` to variable `x`, but testing some unknown variable `returnvalue` in your `if` statement. You should be checking for `if x = 6` instead, or `resultvalue = msgbox()`.

```
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
x = msgbox("Do you wish for windows Shutdown?" , 4 + 16, "Confirm")
If x = 6 Then
    shell.run "||||File Adress||||test.bat"
End If
```